# How do I insert a file's contents into each of a list of files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have 2 files, one with list of text files and the other with content I want to add.

I can't seem to be able to use the variable in a bash script.

the script is like this:

```sh
for name in $(cat /home/stuff/list)
do 
  keysss=`cat /home/stuff/test`
  sed -i "27i $keysss " $name
done
```

This way it gives an error. Other ways I've tried print the word but I want to print the content of it into file

ps. the files contain ca root certificates

Comment: Try `sed -i "s/27i/$keysss/g"` <- The " are to be exchanged with ' if you don't want $keysss to be parsed as variable.

Comment: i need to parse it as variable, that's the issue

i dont't want to print $keysss but the content of that file

Comment: tested some more, it's not possible when the "test" file is filled with a root certificate, regex from sed reads it improperly for this command to work.

Comment: [Useless use of backticks](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the file into a variable and inserting that content with `i` command (which will fail for certain cases like the fail containing newlines/they would need to get escaped), you should use the `r` command to append the text directly:

```sh
for name in $(cat /home/stuff/list); do 
  sed -i "27r /home/stuff/test" $name
done
```

To avoid the [issues with backticks](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks) it would be better to use:

```sh
while read -r name; do 
  sed -i "27r /home/stuff/test" "$name"
done < /home/stuff/list
```

Or more simply:

```sh
xargs -rd '\n' -- sed -i "27r /home/stuff/test" < /home/stuff/list
```

Comment: Two (now deleted) answers suggested the same thing.

Comment: What are you trying to tell me? I didn't copy my answer. I don't even remember other answers being given.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't implying you copied (FWIW, I upvoted this answer). It just amused me that two users suggested the same thing a month ago, then deleted their answers, then you came along and also suggest `r`. History repeating? https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWM5G.png

Comment: I see. Well, `r` is the obvious solution for this. I just wonder why the others did delete their correct answers. And whether the OP cares at all.